# retornar vista con parametros laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un problema al pasar una variable a un vista  (probé y si esta trayendo los datos de la BD), cuando mando la variable me aparece como no encontrada, ya que es dentro de una sesión, también probe con un `Auth::book`
pero no resulta.

Aquí esta la ruta:

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
```

Aquí los métodos del controlador:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}


public function index()
{
    $booksFounded = Book::all();
    //var_dump($booksFounded);
    //die();
    return view('dashboard', $booksFounded);

}
```

la vista:

```html
@include('layouts/headerUser')
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-4" >
            <h3 class="panel-title"> Bienvenido </h3>
            <br>
            @foreach ($booksFounded as $book)
                <p>This is book {{ $book->name }}</p>
            @endforeach

            {{-- @foreach ($booksFounded as $book)
                <p>This is book {{ $book->name }}</p>
            @endforeach --}}
            
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}" >
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Cerrar Sesion</button>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
@include('layouts/footer')
```

Quedo atento a comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar variables del controlador a la vista tienes estas opciones:

**MÉTODO COMPACT**

```
public function index()
{
    $booksFounded = Book::all();
    //var_dump($booksFounded);
    //die();
    return view('dashboard', compact('booksFounded'));

}
```

**Aclaraciones**

- La variable se pasa dentro del método `compact()`.
- La variable se pasa entre comillas.

**MÉTODO WITH**

```
public function index()
{
    $booksFounded = Book::all();
    //var_dump($booksFounded);
    //die();
    return view('dashboard')->with("booksFounded", $booksFounded);

}
```

**Aclaraciones**

- Le pasas al método `with` entre comillas la key con la cual vas a identificar a la variable y posterior separado por una coma la variable.